# Can one become an attorney without a law degree?

Tags: united-states, legal-education

Can one become an attorney without a law degree in the United States, such as by passing the state bar exam? Which States in the U.S. allow this?

Comment: This depends on the state/country. There is no single answer.

Comment: @MSalters Thanks. I narrowed the scope down.

Comment: It is also worth noting that it is possible to be a judge without being a lawyer in many states where it is not possible to be a lawyer without passing the bar exam. For example, New York and Colorado, where I am admitted to practice, are among them.

Comment: For what it is worth, well under 1% of U.S. lawyers are admitted to practice in this manner.

Answer (score 7):

California, Virginia, Vermont, and Washington allow a person to substitute a pattern of study in a judges or lawyer's office. In California, this is per [rule 4.29](https://www.calbar.ca.gov/Portals/0/documents/rules/Rules_Title4_Div1-Adm-Prac-Law.pdf) of the California Bar, and [rule 6](http://www.courts.wa.gov/court_rules/?fa=court_rules.display&group=ga&set=APR&ruleid=gaapr06) of the Washington Supreme Court. These states require the candidate to be supervised and tutored by a practicing attorney or judge, which makes it challenging to actually satisfy the requirement.
There are also provisions whereby one might substitute the fact of being a practicing lawyer in a common law jurisdiction (which opens the theoretical possibility that one might not have attended law school in that country).

Comment: My grandfather "read the law" in North Carolina (in the early 20th century, so it's likely that this is no longer possible in North Carolina) and served as a county judge in addition to his private law practice, so I presume that being supervised by a practicing judge or lawyer only applies before being admitted to the bar.

Comment: @phoog Many states allow someone who is not a lawyer to serve as a judge. Colorado has 3-4 of them, but New York State, for example, has a great many.

Answer (score 3):

New York allows a person to take the bar exam after "study in a law office" and not just after law school.

See Rule 520.4 (https://www.nycourts.gov/ctapps/520rules10.htm#2).

The current version of the rule (my recollection is that it didn't always require this) requires essentially that the 1L curriculum has been taken at a law school, successfully, followed by ~3 years of law office study.

Answer (score 0):

**Can one become an attorney without a law degree?**

**[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)**

**Yes**, assuming "attorney" is synonymous with "solicitor" and not "lawyer" because...

> Unlike terms such as solicitor or barrister, lawyer has no defined meaning in UK law. Anyone can call themselves a lawyer, regardless of whether they have any professional legal qualifications or not.
>
> [Source: SRA](https://www.sra.org.uk/consumers/choosing/legal-jargon-explained/)

But:

> It is a criminal offence for someone to call themselves a solicitor or act as a solicitor if they are not on the roll of solicitors.
>
> [Source: SRA](https://www.sra.org.uk/consumers/problems/fraud-dishonesty/bogus-fake-solicitors/)

To qualify as a solicitor without a law degree, one needs to follow the [Solicitors Qualifying Examination (SQE)](https://www.sra.org.uk/become-solicitor/sqe/) route, and must:

> - have a degree in any subject or equivalent level 6 qualification
> - pass both stages of the SQE assessment
> - [*have*] two years' full-time (or equivalent) qualifying work experience
> - pass <strike>our</strike> [*the SRA*] character and suitability requirements.